# HybridAuth not responding

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I've installed and configured HybridAuth based on their documentations.

When I try to do-a sign-in on a particular social network, this comes up :
[image]

Any tips would be highly appreciated!. :)

Comment: have you enabled debug mode? http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html

Comment: Where do I place the debug file? I've enabled debug, but it gives `'debug_file' does not exit.`

Comment: place where he can read and give full path

Comment: I've checked the logs and found this :

`Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( Facebook ), User not connected to the provider. Try to authenticate..
DEBUG -- 119.92.79.160 -- 2013-07-10T14:05:41+00:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Facebook ), no params given. Trying to get the sotred for this provider.`